Two dimensional array, filter and return new array with the indexes rather than values
I have a two dimensional array that in turn has an object with an additional array.
I want to filter the array and return a new array with the index that matches the criteria with the object.
For example:
One array: gp[0][0].pts = [10,5,40,30,95,5,11,85];
I want to search the array and return values above or equal to 20.  This would be [40, 30, 95, 85];
I want the new array to return the indexes for these, so in this case it would be [2,3,4,7]
The code below returns the correct numbers but I want the indexes instead.
Thanks in advance.


const gp = [
  [{
    "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
  }, {
    "pts": [2, 1, 4]
  }, {
    "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
  }]
];


for (let n = 0; n <= 2; n++) {
  const race = gp[0][n].pts.filter(v => +v >= 20).map(Number);
  if (race.length) {
    console.log(`race at n=${n}: ${race}`);
  };
};




I think you could just map each element of race's index in gp[0][n].pts: raceIndices = race.map(r => gp[0][n].pts.indexOf(r))

so in this case it would be [2,3,4,7]. Are you saying the final result should be [2,3,4,7], or do you want it to be [[2,3,4,7], [], [1, 2, 3]] or [[{ pts: [2,3,4,7]}, ...]]? Please include the actual end result desired.

And here is another solution on the basis of Array.forEach() and Array.reduce():


const gp = [
  [{
    "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
  }, {
    "pts": [2, 1, 4]
  }, {
    "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
  }]
];


gp[0].forEach(({pts},n)=>{ 
  const race=pts.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
    if(+c>=20) a.push(i);
    return a;
  },[]);
  if (race.length) {
    console.log(`race at n=${n}: ${race}`);
  };
});




lol, you posted the same solution as mine, kindred  minds

Yes, Alexander, more or less at the same time. Sorry for the redundancy. I have been admiring your deeply thought through solutions for quite some time.

it's a nice place here to learn from each other

Instead of first filtering, and then mapping, first map your "number" to a "number and index", then filter:


const gp = [{
  pts: [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
}, {
  pts: [2, 1, 4]
}, {
  pts: [14, 22, 41, 23]
}];


function testOver(data, threshold) {
  return data.map(({ pts }, n) => {
    const result = pts
      .map((num, index) => ({num, index}))
      .filter(({ num }) => num >= threshold);
    
    if (result.length) {
      return { [n]: result };
    }

    return false;
  }).filter(Boolean);
}

console.log(testOver(gp, 20));



Or if you know your downstream code will never need both the index and the associated value, return {n: result.map(({ index }) => index)} instead, of course.
Alternatively, use reduce as mentioned by Alexander Nenashev

You could achieve that with the following
1- Map each value to an object containing both value and index
2- Filter objects with value >= 20
3- Map back to indices


let gp = [];
gp[0] = [];
gp[0][0] = {};
gp[0][0].pts = [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85];

gp[0][1] = {};
gp[0][1].pts = [2, 1, 4];

gp[0][2] = {};
gp[0][2].pts = [14, 22, 41, 23];



const filteredIndicesPerRace = {};

gp[0].forEach((race, raceIndex) => {
  filteredIndicesPerRace[raceIndex] = race.pts
    .map((value, index) => ({
      value,
      index
    })) 
    .filter(obj => obj.value >= 20) 
    .map(obj => obj.index); 
});

console.log(filteredIndicesPerRace);




First, map the arrays to [element, index] pairs. Then filter, then extract just the indices.


const gp = [
  [{
    "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
  }, {
    "pts": [2, 1, 4]
  }, {
    "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
  }]
]

gp[0].forEach(({pts}, n) => {
  let race = pts.map((e,i) => [e,i]).filter(([e]) => +e >= 20).map(([,i]) => i)
  if(race.length) console.log(`race at n=${n}: ${race}`)
})




If you want a performant fast solution, use Array#reduce() and collect indices without intermediate arrays (waste of time & space):


const gp = [
  [{
    "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
  }, {
    "pts": [2, 1, 4]
  }, {
    "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
  }]
];


for (let n = 0; n < gp[0].length; n++) {
  const race = gp[0][n].pts.reduce((r, v, i) => (v >= 20 && r.push(i), r), []);
  if (race.length) {
    console.log(`race at n=${n}: ${race}`);
  };
};



And a benchmark:
` Chrome/124
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=3        |       n=30        |       n=300       |      n=3000     
Alexander      ■ 1.00x x10m 370 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 382 | ■ 1.00x x100k 371 | ■ 1.00x x10k 359
Andrew Parks     3.59x  x1m 133 |   3.66x x100k 140 |   3.99x  x10k 148 |   4.46x  x1k 160
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunk = [{
    "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
  }, {
    "pts": [2, 1, 4]
  }, {
    "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
  }];

const $input = [];
const gp = [$input];

// @benchmark Andrew Parks
gp[0].forEach(({pts}, n) => {
  pts.map((e,i) => [e,i]).filter(([e]) => +e >= 20).map(([,i]) => i);
})

// @benchmark Alexander
for (let n = 0; n < gp[0].length; n++) {
  gp[0][n].pts.reduce((r, v, i) => (v >= 20 && r.push(i), r), [])
}

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Just for the fun of adding another solution you can use flatMap


const gp = [
    [{
      "pts": [10, 5, 40, 30, 95, 5, 11, 85]
    }, {
      "pts": [2, 1, 4]
    }, {
      "pts": [14, 22, 41, 23]
    }]
  ];
  
 gp[0].map(n=>{
    let array1 = n.pts.flatMap((elem,idx)=>{
      if(elem>=20)
        { return idx

        }else{
          return []
        }
    })
    if(array1.length) console.log(array1)
  })



